# Django Oscar on Windows error

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

After forking app following django-oscar documentaion, It is giving this error:

**ImportError: No module named 'apps\promotions'**

Do not know what I did wrong

What I have done:

python manage.py oscar_fork_app promotions apps

Creating package apps\promotions

Creating admin.py

Creating app config

Creating models.py

Creating migrations folder

The final step is to add 'apps\promotions' to INSTALLED_APPS
(replacing the equivalent Oscar app). This can be achieved using
Oscar's get_core_apps function - e.g.:

```
# settings.py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.auth',
...
]
from oscar import get_core_apps
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + get_core_apps(
['apps\promotions'])

INSTALLED_APPS = [

'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.flatpages',
'compressor',
"django.contrib.admin",
'widget_tweaks',
"paypal",
] + get_core_apps(['apps.promotions'])
```

Comment: Have you created an app.py in which you define the application?

Comment: Why do you have defined INSTALLED_APPS twice?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + get_core_apps(['apps.promotions'])
```

https://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/customisation.html#replace-oscar-s-app-with-your-own-in-installed-apps

Comment: NameError: name 'INSTALLED_APPS' is not defined

Comment: If I make it so:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ..
]

INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + get_core_apps(['apps.promotions'])

ImportError: No module named 'apps\\promotions'